Get/Take/Earn Architecture bachelor degree. Which one is correct?
I was writing my goals when I came across a question.
Which one is correct?
Get Architecture bachelor degree./
Take Architecture bachelor degree./
Earn Architecture bachelor degree.
Thanks for your help.

You can take, earn, gain, complete, receive, obtain A degree. It doesn't really make any difference how you describe it - it's the same degree, however you got it (my default choice of verb). But all your examples are incorrect, because they don't include the indefinite article. Note that you can also take a degree course, even if you don't successfully complete the course and pass the exams, so I'd avoid that one.

You get/earn/obtain A degree IN architecture

get is earn but it is informal, if you're writing a resume, for example.


Earn a Bachelor of Arts in Architecture. / Earn an Architecture degree.

Fine.

Get a Bachelor of Arts in Architecture. / Get an Architecture degree.

This is acceptable in casual speech. In ordinary conversation you'd often say "get". When writing a formal school paper the word "earn" sounds more official.

Take a Bachelor of Arts in Architecture. / Take an Architecture degree.

Not really. (At least from the perspective of US English.). You "take" classes though.
Other valid choices: "obtain", "receive", "complete". These are not synonymous and equally interchangeable. Each word carries it's own certain sensibility. For example, "obtain" sounds rather formal. "complete" is matter-of-fact.  "receive" is more passive.
